# TDUnit fails to find tables?

Tags: .net, tdd

I am playing with A database which works using Entity Framework.
It works when I connect via ADO.Net

When I connect via TDUnit, it fails, saying that tableName is not valid.

In config.xml I have tried putting table name "schemaName.tableName" or name="tableName" to no avail.

My connection string runs as this : connectionString="data source=machineName;Inital Catalog=DbName;integratd security=True....

Any ideas ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution : 
TD unit does not understand schema.tableName in XML.

When bulding the queries, it issued the following sql : insert into [SchemaName.Table] ... which of course is incorrect.

I used the following workaround : 
Defined the schema as default for the connected user
Removed the schema name from my xml file.

This is a temporary solution since if I need to load tables contained in two schemas, I'm stuck.
I'll contact the author of the TDUnit, in case I missed something...